# Splitting string into pairs with c#

Tags: c#, string

Is there a way to break a string into pairs without looking at indexes? e.g.
TVBMCVTVFGTVTB would be broken into a list of strings as such:

[TV,BM,CV,TV,FG,TV,TB]

Perhaps I should have worded the question to state is their a function similar to string.join, or string.split when working with strings to break them into groups.

Comment: What's wrong with looking at indexes?

Comment: @RQDQ Indexes are fine I just wanted to avoid walking a string with substring.

Comment: @digEmAll: I've done this by looking at indexes and using substring. I was curious if there is a a great way to do this that I have not found.  string.join was a nice discovery for creating delimited strings.

Comment: yes, `string.Join` is basically the opposite of what you need. `string.Split` looks similar, but it needs a char as splitter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like some esoteric solutions:

**1)**

```
string s = "TVBMCVTVFGTVTB";
var splitted = Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length)
                         .GroupBy(x => x / 2)
                         .Select(x => new string(x.Select(y => s[y]).ToArray()))
                         .ToList();
```

**2)**

```
string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";
var splitted = Enumerable.Range(0, (s.Length + 1) / 2)
                         .Select(i => 
                                 s[i * 2] + 
                                 ((i * 2 + 1 < s.Length) ? 
                                 s[i * 2 + 1].ToString() : 
                                 string.Empty))
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm choosing this as it gets away from using substring, but I will stick with the substring version for checked in code.

Comment: @jparram: well even if my solution is working, I don't think it's the best in term of readability (it was a sort of provocation... ;) ). An old good for-loop will be more readable and also slightly faster IMO. And, BTW, substring is completely equal to new string() in this case, if not faster (because new string must pass through the creation of a new array).

Comment: @jparram: I am not picking on @digEmAll at all but why the aversion to substring, and what do you think this code is doing differently that makes it better, and do you really think this code more clearly expresses the intent?

Comment: @Jason: The aversion stems from the time I spent not knowing about string.Join. The question may have been poorly worded.  I do not really think this code more clearly expresses the intent...however it answers the question without using substring.

Comment: @jparram: That doesn't make any sense. You're averse to `String.Substring` because you weren't aware of `String.Join`? I don't see the connection. So the code doesn't more clearly express the intent, yet because of this odd aversion to `String.Substring`, you're going to use it? Again, I want to make it clear that I'm not picking on @digEmAll (he's just gave a clever answer to your question within the unusual guidelines you gave, something I didn't do), but this code is actually really bad. It's unclear, it's not maintainable, and it probably has similar performance characteristics as mine.

Comment: @jparram: The code in this answer does meet the guidelines that you gave, but my point is that the guidelines you gave are ridiculous. I point this all out so that someone else doesn't stumble upon this question in the future and think this answer is the way to proceed.

Comment: I think @Jason is right. Use this code if you like it, but in order to make this question an example for future readers, you shouldn't mark my answer as accepted. ;-) (BTW, added a new version, still very strange but a bit more readable)

Comment: @Jason: My first comment in this thread states that I am sticking with a substring version.  I also stated more than once that I probably worded the question poorly.

Answer (score 7):

Oh come on, just use indexes like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<string> TakeEvery(this string s, int count) {
        int index = 0;
        while(index < s.Length) {
            if(s.Length - index >= count) {
                yield return s.Substring(index, count);
            }
            else {
                yield return s.Substring(index, s.Length - index);
            }
            index += count;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added no guard clauses.

Usage:

```
var items = "TVBMCVTVFGTVTB".TakeEvery(2);
foreach(var item in items) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: I should have put sarcasm tags around my comment.  Sheesh.

Comment: @jparram: There was not an error. I have reverted your changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you REALLY want to avoid using indexes...

You could use a Regex "\w\w" or "\w{2,2}" or some variation like that and [MSDN - Regex.Matches method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx) to get a MatchCollection which would contain the matches as pairs of characters. Change \w in the regex pattern to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

while (original.Length > 0)
{
    result.Add(new String(original.Take(2).ToArray()));
    original = new String(original.Skip(2).ToArray());
}

return result;
```

The LINQ probably uses indices somewhere internally, but I didn't touch any of them so I consider this valid. It works for odd-length originals, too.

### Edit:

Thanks **Heinzi** for the correction. Demo: http://rextester.com/MWCKYD83206

Comment: +1: It might not have the best performance, but this is definitely the most readable solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, because IEnumerable<char>.ToString does not return what you expect. `new String(original.Take(2).ToArray())` fixes the issue (analogous for the second line).

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string into a char array and then iterate along that making new strings out of pairs of characters.

Comment: This is a simple, robust way to do it.

Comment: Actually conversion to char array is useless (and it would introduce an overhead). Strings are `IEnumerable<char>` with `O(1)` indexed access, just like a char array.

Answer (score 0):

### 1) Split list into pairs

```
var s = "TVBMCVTVFGTVTB";
var pairs = Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length / 2)
                      .Select(i => String.Concat(s.Skip(i * 2).Take(2)));
```

This will work if you know that `s` always is of even length, or you don't accept, or don't care about, ending with singletons for strings with odd length.

### 2) Split list into pairs - include any singleton remainders

If you want to include singleton remainders, for odd length strings, you can simply use ceiling:

```
var s = "TVBMCVTVFGTVTB";
var pairs = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling(s.Length / 2D))
                      .Select(i => String.Concat(s.Skip(i * 2).Take(2)));
```