# Split string two by two and append to list

Tags: c#

I have string like this:

```
string mystring = "123456"
```

And I want to split two by two to 12 34 56.

Pseudocode:

```
var list = new List<int>();
foreach(var e in something){
    string mystring ="123456";
    var split = ...
    // convert the splitted string
    list.Add(convertedString);
}
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting string into pairs with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926432/splitting-string-into-pairs-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Another way which may or may not be easier to understand

```
public static IEnumerable<int> SplitInts(this string source)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i += 2)
        yield return int.Parse(source.Substring(i, Math.Min(2, source.Length - i)));
}
```

**Usage**

```
var test = "23456";
foreach (var item in test.SplitInts())
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
23
45
6
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vn3REs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var str = "123456";
var intList = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / 2)
            .Select(i => Convert.ToInt32( string.Concat(str.Skip(i * 2).Take(2)))).ToList();
```

if you console log the result:

```
foreach(var e in intList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e);
}

Output list will contain elements like `12, 34, 56 respectively.`
```